# Skype not working in CentOS 6.2

Tags: linux, skype, rpm, centos-6

I tried to install Skype on CentOS 6.2. I downloaded Skype's rpm package from [here](http://www.skype.com/intl/en-us/get-skype/on-your-computer/linux/downloading.fedora) and tried this command to install – but it's giving an error like this:

```
[root@localhost Downloads]# rpm -ivh skype-4.0.0.7-fedora.i586.rpm 
error: Failed dependencies:
    alsa-lib >= 1.0.23 is needed by skype-4.0.0.7-fc16.i586
    libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.15) is needed by skype-4.0.0.7-fc16.i586
```

So I tried this command:

```
[root@localhost Downloads]# rpm -ivh --nodeps skype-4.0.0.7-fedora.i586.rpm 
Preparing...                ########################################### [100%]
   1:skype                  ########################################### [100%]
```

The Skype icon will appear in Applications » Internet » Skype, but when clicking the icon nothing's happening.

So I installed `libstdc++6-4.7.0-0.6-mdv2012.0.i586.rpm` with this command:

```
[root@localhost Downloads]# rpm -ivh libstdc++6-4.7.0-0.6-mdv2012.0.i586.rpm 
warning: libstdc++6-4.7.0-0.6-mdv2012.0.i586.rpm: Header V3 DSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID 26752624: NOKEY
Preparing...                ########################################### [100%]
    file /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6 from install of libstdc++6-4.7.0-0.6.i586 conflicts with file from package libstdc++-4.4.6-3.el6.i686
```

It's still not working.

Comment: Did you try running it from a terminal?

Comment: yes... it is giving the error like this [suraj@localhost ~]$ skype
skype: /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.15' not found (required by skype)

Comment: Check your formatting please, next time indent code using `Ctrl-K`.

Comment: Maybe you should have listened when rpm told you there was a problem then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change root user

> su -

Install Needed Dependencies

> yum install alsa-lib.i686 fontconfig.i686 freetype.i686 glib2.i686 libSM.i686 libXScrnSaver.i686 libXi.i686 libXrandr.i686 libXrender.i686 libXv.i686 libstdc++.i686 pulseaudio-libs.i686 qt.i686 qt-x11.i686 zlib.i686

Download Latest Skype Static Package

> cd /tmp
>
> wget http://www.skype.com/go/getskype-linux-beta-static

Extract Skype

> mkdir /opt/skype
>
> tar xvf skype_static* -C /opt/skype --strip-components=1

Create libtiff.so.4 link

> cd /usr/lib
>
> ln -s libtiff.so.3 /usr/lib/libtiff.so.4

Create Launcher, Link icons, lang and sounds

> ln -s /opt/skype/skype.desktop /usr/share/applications/skype.desktop
>
> ln -s /opt/skype/icons/SkypeBlue_48x48.png /usr/share/icons/skype.png
>
> ln -s /opt/skype/icons/SkypeBlue_48x48.png /usr/share/pixmaps/skype.png
>
> touch /usr/bin/skype
>
> chmod 755 /usr/bin/skype

Open /usr/bin/skype with text editor and add following content:

> #!/bin/sh
>
> export SKYPE_HOME="/opt/skype"
>
> $SKYPE_HOME/skype --resources=$SKYPE_HOME $*

Start Skype

From command line use skype command

> skype